# While deploying my java application on Docker container , I am getting while fetching the path

Tags: java, docker, maven

I am fetching the file from a folder in my application it is working fine when I am running the application from IDE and when I am building the project and packaging is jar it is not containing the folder.
And when I am running application in docker it is giving error file not found.

I am new in docker can anyone help me. What is the problem?

```
  FROM adoptopenjdk:14-jre-hotspot
  RUN mkdir /opt/batch-processor \
  && mkdir /opt/batch-processor/data \
  COPY ./target/batch-processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/batch-processor
  WORKDIR /opt/batch-processor
  CMD ["java", "-jar", "batch-processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```

I am also adding my directory structure, can anyone also tell why I data folder is not getting created in a jar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- You need to split line #2 into a `RUN` line and a `COPY` line otherwise the `RUN` trumps the `COPY` (which isn't effected):

```
RUN mkdir /opt/batch-processor && mkdir /opt/batch-processor/data
COPY ./target/batch-processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/batch-processor
```

- Move the `WORKDIR` higher, this creates and changes to the directory, simplifying things:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:14-jre-hotspot

WORKDIR /opt/batch-processor

RUN mkdir ./data
COPY ./target/batch-processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar .

CMD ["java", "-jar", "batch-processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar"]
```